# How can I push the undoing of marking as accepted an answer I gave in favor of marking as accepted a better answer given by someone else?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepting

It happens from time to time/all the time that I realize that the answer someone else has given to a question is better than the answer I gave.
This also happens in situations where the questioner has already marked my answer as "accepted".
I then feel embarrassed.

Apart from informing the questioner in a comment or via an edit of my own answer that I think another answer is better than the one I gave, what other options do I have as an answerer to push for the marking to be changed so that instead of my answer, the better answer is marked as "accepted"?

Comment: Good question, but I fear you may be doomed.  In at least some cases, once an answer is given that works, the OP goes away and doesn't come back.  By explicitly calling attention to another answer you think is better, you'll at least help out someone else in the future.

Comment: You could edit in a "See this answer" banner. Unfortunately quote marking is no longer as good as it once was

Comment: SE will most likely [unpin the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?cb=1) network-wide soon (see also [our own meta discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?cb=1)), so if the other answer has more votes than yours it will be shown on top. Your answer will still be marked as Accepted but it will be less prominent.